Change default model for LlamaIndex.TS
I'm a student and I have a project to create a chatbot using RAG. I use the LLamaIndex.TS library to create the chatbot. It almost done but there was a problem. The default model of the library is OPEN_AI and it need a payment to use API key from OPEN_AI. Are there any ways to change the model this library used to Gemini model?
I try this code, but it can't read the llm attribute
const embed = new GeminiEmbedding()
const gemini = new Gemini()
const service = serviceContextFromServiceContext({
  llm: gemini,
  promptHelper: {},
  embedModel: embed,
})

